# Blazor - Field validation triggering on multiple elements when one element loses focus

Tags: validation, blazor, blazor-server-side, data-annotations

New to Blazor and DataAnnotations.  I have having a strange validation issue on my form.  I have 7 fields some are inputs, others are drop downs, and 2 are date pickers(MudBlazor).  All are Required except for one date field.  If I click into one of the inputs, let's say LinkText, if there is no text and it loses focus it shows the required field validation message.  I guess this is typical for Blazor forms?  But the strange thing is I have a field called EffectiveDate that is Required, and that message always shows when one of the other fields is touched.  Why would this be happening?  This happens BEFFORE I try to submit the form.
    
This is a sample from my model class:

```cs
[Required]
[StringLength(2000, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(WebResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(WebResource.LinkTextMaxLength))]
public string LinkText { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = ValidationConstants.DateFormat)]
public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }

[DateGreaterThan(nameof(EffectiveDate), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(WebResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(WebResource.DateRangeValidation))]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = ValidationConstants.DateFormat)]
public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

Why would the EffectiveDate validation be triggered from LinkText or any other required field?  Am I doing something wrong, or missing something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: it looks like your ExpirationDate has a dependency on EffectiveDate through the [DateGreaterThan] decorator.  So, since they're effectively connected this way, it might be what causes them to trigger each other's validation.

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, but that code is not being triggered

Comment: Maybe provide a minimum viable reproduction?  Do you have some more sample code you can share? I'm afraid there's not enough here to really work with.

Comment: Sorry about the small amount of code, wasn't sure it was needed.  I did find the answer.  
In the markup, on the date picker I had this:
                                   For="@(() => ResourceAsset.EffectiveDate)"
                                   Error=@(!IsValid && hasDateErrors)
I had to remove the For=".." Because of some custom validation code that would trigger for some reason.